# How to update PHP SSL version?

Tags: php, macos, ssl, openssl, composer-php

i have a problem when run `composer update` or install new package
i get this message :

```
    Failed to download tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/zipball/0ed4a2ea4e0902dac0489e6436ebcd5bbcae9757" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
```

im on MacOS 10.13.3, using mamp 3.5, 
I updated my git version to 2.16.3 but **i dont know now how to update my SSL version**
When i run `php -i | grep "SSL Version"` i have:

```
SSL Version => OpenSSL/0.9.8zd
```

when i run `php -i l grep OpenSSL` i have:

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.6.10

(...)

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
```

how to update that?
thanks

Comment: Google `update openssl on mac` and see 2,190,000 results Lots of which are on SO

Comment: Or https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x

Comment: the problem is not realy in the general version, when i run `openssl version -a` i have `LibreSSL 2.2.7` , the problem is in the php version (thx for your comment)

Comment: Solved by installing php 7 with brew and change the path location on my  .bash_profile file. thanks guys